# How to set up Red5 recorder in an web application

Tags: video-capture

I know that Red5 is a free video recorder and can be used in web applications.
I'm using Jboss server for my web application.
I downloaded the Red5 recorder and could not find any set up information.

Does anyone know how to add(set up) red5 in the application ??

Comment: For the records, have a look at the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128899/simple-alternatives-to-red5-recorder-and-server-for-webcam-video-capture

Answer (score 0):

I came across this quick unofficial setup guide:
http://fms.denniehoopingarner.com/newapp.html
Let me know if it is helpful.