# Flash Media Server Buying Alternatives

Tags: flash, red5, rtmfp

I m attempting to build a video chat application. I want to use rtmfp host with Adobe Media Server 5 Professional however, its very expensive to purchase so I'm in the process of looking for other options. I was considering using Cirrus which is free open source but it has limited amount of connections and has other severe limitations that it wouldn't be feasible for me to opt for. Red 5 is another free open source rtmfp server but I have no knowledge of Java which is a big put off. The only other alternative is using Adobe Amazon web services. But I have no idea of the costs.  I was wondering if anybody has used it what your experience was and the costs of running it? By the way if you can think of any other servers I could I appreciate if you could tell me. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Red5 can anything, but RTMFP (the p2p stuff).

Cirrus is deprecated by Adobe.

If you need RTMFP, you could use [Influxis](http://influxis.com/streaming/pricing/) service.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Alexander I appreciate it!. I do require RTMFP. Influxis I look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently evaluating and reading the [rtmp-nginx-module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module). It *looks* more stable and very well documented than the other peers I've tried:

- RTMPLite: Works well with VideoIO.swf however it's not easily extensible.
- Red5: Good luck getting it working correctly!

[Copied from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20596437/161278).